# How to compile this dll using SDL with MinGW?

Tags: c, dll, makefile, sdl-2

Okay so I have been working on this fork for over a year now and this thing doesn't want to compile as dll on x86-64 mingw running on Windows 10. I am following the original instructions: https://github.com/kometbomb/klystron/wiki/libksnd#compiling-the-library

And this is what it tells (there are other errors which can be fixed but this infuriates me the most):

```
Building ksndstatic.lib...
make: lib: No such file or directory
make: [Makefile:117: bin.release/libksndstatic.a] Error 127 (ignored)
Linking ksnd.dll...
Building ksnd.lib...
make: lib: No such file or directory
make: [Makefile:127: bin.release/ksnd.dll] Error 127 (ignored)
```

What the hell is `lib`?! Is this Visual Studio thing or outdated name for `dlltool` or `libtool`? What kind of zombie toolchain is this even made for? (hint: year 2007 or even earlier)

This can be relatively easy compiled as a submodule using the same windows mingw toolchain: https://github.com/kometbomb/klystrack
Or, if this does not work, try my fork: https://github.com/ltva1/klystrack

So the question is how to compile it at least with SDL linkage? Maybe I will be able to get it to work with native OSes APIs but at least I want a dll I can use in other C/C++ project.

Comment: A wonky makefile, probably. Add `--trace` to `make` and show the last few lines before the error.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MVDJh6zL
@HolyBlackCat

Comment: Yep, a poorly written makefile. It uses `ifdef COMSPEC` to check if it should run this MSVC thingie. Try undefining this env variable in the shell before building.

Comment: Well what I did: `set COMSPEC=`, then the same `make` command but it still prints the exact same message. Maybe there's a different way to undefine it?

Comment: Add `undefine COMSPEC` on top of the makefile.

Comment: I added it to both `Makefile` and `common.mk` and it stopped giving me the errors. Thanks. Now I just need to fix all the other errors. I will close the question if I will succeed.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/h3Yc3NmW now it gives these errors. I tried to add `-lwsock32` but it does nothing.

Comment: Why `-lwsock32`? Googling the function name leads [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-waveoutwrite), which says it's defined in `Winmm.lib`, meaning the flag you need is `-lwinmm`.

Comment: Oh my this is so stupid, the flag was in `ifdef COMSPEC`! Anyway, I am going to write a test program and if it work I will close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the static linking works at least. There are some problems with audio buffer but this is outside of this question scope. I followed the advices in the thread above: undefined COMSPEC and added linkage to winmm in the case COMSPEC is not defined. See makefile changes there: https://github.com/LTVA1/klystron/commit/47e4c31c86833ce8d879d4474ba4045e95ea1a22 (COMSPEC undefine thing is commented out so main project which uses the repo as submodule gets compiled; `-lwsock32` thing is unneded actually). At least I get the sound from the thing. Will wait 2 days to accept as answer.

Comment: I suggest to either explain the steps you did to solve this (that's the point of posting an answer after all), or delete the question altogether.